# Bootstrap Laravel with table and how to fit screen

Tags: php, laravel

how to make my program can follow resolution my screen, or any idea to make my program make better.
I guess my bootstrap is problem because program display is not fit screen, I hope it can fit on my screen.

[image: program display]

and here is my index.blade.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Import Excel Ke Database Dengan Laravel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <center>
            <h2>Import Excel Ke Database Dengan Laravel</h2>
            <h3><a target="_blank" href="https://www.malasngoding.com/">www.malasngoding.com</a></h3>
        </center>

        {{-- notifikasi form validasi --}}
        @if ($errors->has('file'))
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('file') }}</strong>
        </span>
        @endif

{{-- notifikasi sukses --}}
        @if ($sukses = Session::get('sukses'))
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button> 
            <strong>{{ $sukses }}</strong>
        </div>
        @endif

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-5" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#importExcel">
                IMPORT EXCEL
        </button>
<!-- Import Excel -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="importExcel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <form method="post" action="/transaksi/import_excel" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h3 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Import Excel</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">

                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <label>Pilih file excel</label>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="file" name="file" required="required">
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Import</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I'm using laravel 8.6 and php.

There is my table code, I was tried add `container-fluid` but still didn't work

```html
        <table class='table table-bordered'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>No</th>
                    <th>id_subdist</th>
                    <th>id_toko</th>
                    <th>id_dso</th>
                    <th>id_rso</th>
                    <th>id_channel</th>
                    <th>id_outlet</th>
                    <th>id_produk</th>
                    <th>qty_pcs</th>
                    <th>harga</th>
                    <th>nama_promo</th>
                    <th>free_goods</th>
                    <th>total_qty_include_free_goods</th>
                    <th>disc_total</th>
                    <th>jumlah</th>
                    <th>tgl_posting</th>
                    <th>tgl_faktur</th>
                    <th>created_date</th>
                    <th>modified_by</th>
                    <th>modified_date</th>
                    <th>status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @php $i=1 @endphp
                @foreach($transaksi as $s)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $i++ }}</td>
                    <td>{{$s->id_subdist}}</td>
                    <td>{{$s->id_toko}}</td>
                    <td>{{$s->id_dso}}</td>
                    <td>{{$s->id_rso}}</td>
                    <td>{{$s->id_channel}}</td>
                    <td>{{$s->id_outlet}}</td>
                    <td>{{$s->id_produk}}</td>
                    <td>{{$s->qty_pcs}}</td> 
                    <td>{{$s->harga}}</td>
                    <td>{{$s->nama_promo}}</td>
                    <td>{{$s->free_goods}}</td>
                    <td>{{$s->total_qty_include_free_goods}}</td>
                    <td>{{$s->disc_total}}</td> 
                    <td>{{$s->jumlah}}</td>
                    <td>{{$s->tgl_posting}}</td> 
                    <td>{{$s->tgl_faktur}}</td>
                    <td>{{$s->created_date}}</td>
                    <td>{{$s->modified_by}}</td>
                    <td>{{$s->modified_date}}</td>
                    <td>{{$s->status}}</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: use the class ``container-fluid`` instead of ``container`` for the body tag.

Comment: That can't be all your index.blade.php please share your actual code

Comment: @apokryfos, I couldn't to add my full index.blade.php because is limitation in here, 
I was add part of my index.blade.php

Comment: @OMiShah, where i must add `container-fluid`

Comment: check your codes, within the ``<body>`` tag there should be ``<div class="container">``

Comment: @LucasFutami if you don't know where you should add `container-fluid` you should first refer to the official docs, try to understand them and then get back to SO in case you have other questions: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: What's not fitting in your screen is that table so we need to know how it looks like in the view. If it's a normal `<table>` like tag then you can't expect it to wrap around because tables don't generally do that by default

Comment: @apokryfos, I'm apologize. I add table code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `container-fluid` class instead of `container` class if you want full-screen layout.

Your Code:

```
<div class="container">
    ...
</div>
```

Change it to:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    ...
</div>
```

The container class is a fixed width container, meaning its max-width changes at each breakpoint. And .container-fluid is a full width container, spanning full screen of the viewport. Read more at [Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/containers/)

Comment: WoW I was tried and it get better but still need make zoom on my browser set to 67 percent, can possible to add horizontal scroll bar?